# How to make table row with different width when its underneath?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve table design like below
[image]

First row will be collapsed(which is not implemented yet) and the one underneath will appear,I want second row to be shifted a little.To achieve that I used second tbody but seemed too much work to me.Isn't it possible to make it with second tr?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
tr{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
  <table class="table mt-2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Birth date</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Marley</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>mjhonson@mail.com</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>15/05/1990</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>Kirlman</td>
        <td>skirlman@mail.com</td>
        <td>New Jersey</td>
        <td>12/03/1989</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new class for target row.

```
 <tr class="push-right">
   <td>Sam</td>
   <td>Kirlman</td>
   <td>skirlman@mail.com</td>
   <td>New Jersey</td>
   <td>12/03/1989</td>
   <td>Male</td>
   <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
 </tr>
```

First `td` element in row should act like block element so we will be able to assign `margin` property.

```
.push-right {
  td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvLws1z0/)

Comment: Setting a single table cell to `display: block` is a very bad idea.  Having a "block" element inside a table row isn't defined, so it's coincidence, that it currently displays how you want it to. This very easily display differently or break.

Comment: Could you please clarify why it's bad idea? I only know that it will not work in IE versions older than 9.

Comment: I believe I was wrong. I thought this wasn't defined, but now I've found the definition: In a case like this the browser should create an anonymous table cell around the block element, so this will work. However I still think is't a bit fishy. Personally I'd prefer to explicitly add an additional element inside the table cell (Similarly how I did in the first example of my answer).

Comment: Where do you find "the definition"? I mean, what is your reference?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes In the numbered list (item 2.3.): "If a child C of a 'table-row' box is not a 'table-cell', then generate an anonymous 'table-cell' box around C [...]"

Answer (score -1):

Table rows can't have different widths. (Also notice a table row itself can't have a border).

A simple solution could be to add a left padding to the first name column and make a "fake" border on an additional element. However this isn't very flexible, because for example, the table cells can't have a padding.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-item .firstname {
  padding-left: 2em;
  border: none;
}

.sub-item .firstname div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table mt-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Birth date</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstname">Marley</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>mjhonson@mail.com</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
      <td>15/05/1990</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub-item">
      <td class="firstname"><div>Sam</div></td>
      <td>Kirlman</td>
      <td>skirlman@mail.com</td>
      <td>New Jersey</td>
      <td>12/03/1989</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another possibility could be to add an additional column at the beginning. However this may confuse screen readers and hinder accessibility.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sub-item .indent {
  border: 0;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table class="table mt-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Birth date</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstname" colspan="2">Marley</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>mjhonson@mail.com</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
      <td>15/05/1990</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub-item">
      <td class="indent"></td>
      <td class="firstname">Sam</td>
      <td>Kirlman</td>
      <td>skirlman@mail.com</td>
      <td>New Jersey</td>
      <td>12/03/1989</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```